# Autosave stream of all images captured from webcam using C# aforge

Tags: c#, aforge

I am working on a project where I have to automatically capture all images from webcam video source. I am using aforge.net library. I can save one image manually. But I want to save all the streaming images automatically.

How can I auto save streams of those bitmap images from the webcam automatically?

Answer (score 0):

In case when you need to save batch of photos:

- You should make loop in which you will capture image periodically. That simply could be **separate thread** with **while cycle** in it and with **thread.Sleep**.

In case when you need to save video in result:

- You should use **video capturing instead of photo capturing.**